# Migrate deregister

Tags: migrations

For the following question, note that the site is currently running Migrate 2.5, with a plan to upgrade to 2.7.

I have the following migration, as represented by running migrate-status:

`$ drush ms`

```
Group: default         Total  Imported  Unimported  Status  Last imported
 TiWpAuthor             70     64        0           Idle    2015-02-17 21:17:20
 TiWpImage              15525  14643     882         Idle    2015-02-18 17:11:32
 TiWpPost               13417  12638     608         Idle    2015-02-18 16:57:22
```

I would like to deregister the TiWpPost node. So I run the following commands:

`$ drush migrate-deregister TiWpPost`

`Deregistered 'TiWpPost' migration`

`$ drush cc all`

`'all' cache was cleared`

However, when running migrate-status again, the output is unchanged, with the same Total, Imported and Unimported counts for TiWpPost. (I am expecting to see zero in all of these columns.)

Am I missing something in my understanding of how migrate-deregister is meant to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
drush migrate-deregister --orphans
drush migrate-reset-status
drush ms --refresh
```